# Invalid proto.Any import in golang protobuf definiton (github.com/golang) vs (google.golang.org) one

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

There is a simple protofile:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
package x.y;
option go_package = "x.y";

message X {
  google.protobuf.Any x = 1;
}
```

google variant of protobuf installed

```bash
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28
```

When it is generated on CI server or on any of my developer's computer all works fine, import is generated this way:

```golang
import(
   anypb "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb"
)
```

it's fine....

But on MY computer only it generates following way:

```golang
import (
    any1 "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any"
)
```

I understand that it's caused because i've used protobuf before with `github.com/golang/protobuf/...`, but

1. reinstalled `golang`
2. reinstalled `protoc`
3. cleaned `GOPATH`, cleaned `GOROOT`,....
4. no any `go install ... github.com...`
5. anoter user created on computer to check it from another profile
6. whole PATH checked that no alternate protoc-gen-go binaries...

And nothing changed! Event after all reinstallation and from another account it is still

```golang
import (
    any1 "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any"
)
```

Who knows, what i'm missing?

Comment: you only delete the `protoc-gen-go.exe` where in  `where protoc-gen-go.exe`, and reinstall `go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28`

Comment: yes i just deleted my `protoc-gen-go` (`which protoc-gen-go` (linux)), but after re-installation all keeps the same!

Comment: no ideas why, other my developers simply installs same things and all work well...

Answer (score 0):

There are several locations in which go may find a package's dependencies: vendor dir relative to your project or $GOBIN or $GOPATH/bin or $GOPATH/pkg/mod/bin. Have you tried to find & delete "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any" in any of these locations?

Comment: yes, clean it, plan to replace protoc-gen-go with custom `hello world` - so I will sure is it calling protoc-gen-go from place that is expected. Whole $GOROOT, $GOPATH was completly removed and reinstalled. No idea where it get broken one

Comment: 1. $GOROOT - cleaned
2. $GOPATH - cleaned
3. all dirs that somehow in `go env` cleaned
4. golang reinstalled
5. protoc reinstalled with  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads#release-packages libprotoc 3.21.12
6. protoc-gen-go is one file on disk, installed with `go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.28`

But Any is still `any1 "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/any"` no idea why

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Guys from developer command found answer.

It is caused of old invalid `include`

https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1514